# CocoaPods dependency installation error

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoapods, expo

I cant complete "pod install" because of this error. Does anynody know what can be wrong?

```
[!] Error installing FBAudienceNetwork
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/tk/_kklswjd7fq_43ryfj3wwy_m0000gn/T/d20171209-844-4h91ah/file.zip https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FBAudienceNetwork-4.27.0.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9090k    0 9090k    0     0  67122      0 --:--:--  0:02:18 --:--:-- 47482
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

Comment: Possibly crappy internet.

Comment: I am also getting the same error for the last 2 days.

Could anyone check if he can install the pod?

According the [podspec][1] the pod is hosted [here][2].

But nothing exists there for any version of FBAudienceNetwork.




  [1]: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/1/5/FBAudienceNetwork/5.8.0/FBAudienceNetwork.podspec.json
  [2]: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FBAudienceNetwork-5.8.0.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad internet caused this error. I switched to faster network and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your machine has facebook site restricted.

1. Switch to another valid & fast network
2. Run command `pod deintegrate`
3. Run command `pod install`
4. Clear the Derived data
5. Build & Run

**Cheers**

Comment: I am also getting the same error for the last 2 days.

Could anyone check if he can install the pod?

According the [podspec][1] the pod is hosted [here][2].

But nothing exists there for any version of FBAudienceNetwork.




  [1]: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/1/5/FBAudienceNetwork/5.8.0/FBAudienceNetwork.podspec.json
  [2]: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FBAudienceNetwork-5.8.0.zip